# Redirect htaccess regex keeping same URL in browser

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect some pages on a Wordpress site. The pages would have this URL pattern:

```
domain.com/sponsored/something1/.../something2?par_t=param
```

But should be redirected to this one:

```
domain.com/sponsored/?par_t=param
```

So I need remove some parameters from the address but without updating the actual URL in the browser.

I have been tried adding this rule and some others into the .htaccess but no luck so far:

```
RewriteRule ^/sponsored/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ domain.com/sponsored/$2 [QSA]
```

Is this possible? Any idea on how could this be achieved?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty straight forward, probably this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngone on
RewriteRule ^/?sponsored/(.+)/?$ /sponsored/ [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).